# Angular 5 processing results from a POST request

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to convert an app from Angular 1.x to Angular 5.  The app makes a POST request to the server that responds with the results in the form of string, string and array.  Depending upon the value of the 2 strings I then need to use the array in a *ngFor loop to display the results.  This was very easy to achieve in Angular 1 using a factory to make the request and a then clause to break out the various parts of the response.

```
pageFactory.getDetails(getUrl, myDrawing)
    .then(
        function(response) {
            $scope.drawing = response.data.drawing;
            $scope.message = response.data.message;
            $scope.error = response.data.error;
            if ($scope.error != '') {
                    $scope.hide = false;
            }
            $scope.hide2 = false;
    });
```

I just can't find a way to anythin similar to this using Angular 5.  I can make the request in a service using an Observable and a subscribe clause to execute it. What I can't do is break out the 2 strings and the array.

My service is :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {User} from './user';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
};
const usersUrl = 'http://aqp.rvw/processUsers.php';
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('type', 'getAll');


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  users: User[];
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {}
  getUsers(): Observable<object> {
    return this.http.post(usersUrl, formData)
      .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getUsers', []))
      );
  }
```

and main main component

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../user';

import {UserService} from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  response: object;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(response => this.response = {message: response['message'], error: response['error'], users: response['users']});
  }
}
```

My template is:

```
<h2>List of users</h2>
{{message}}
<ul class="users">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.user}}</li>
</ul>
```

My code displays without errors but I don't see a list in my HTML, just the headings.  What changes have I got to make to get this work properly?

Comment: You never assigned the response to your users component property. Try '.subscribe(response => this.users = response.users);

Comment: you are storing your data in `response` variable, but you are trying to iterate `users`. So either assign the data to your `users` array or then `*ngFor="let user of response?.users"`

Comment: Sorry, these answers don't explain how to retrieve the 2 strings plus the array of users from the POST response.  What the API returns is string,string,array.  If it was just an array the answers given would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have more or less solved this.  My service now looks like this

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {catchError, map, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {MyClass} from './myclass';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
};
const usersUrl = 'http://aqp.rvw/processUsers.php';
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('type', 'getAll');


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  answers: MyClass;
  message: string;
  error: string;
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient) {}
  getUsers(): Observable<MyClass[]> {
    return this.http.post<MyClass[]>(usersUrl, formData)
      .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getUsers', []))
      );
  }
}
```

My component is now

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../user';
import {MyClass} from '../myclass';

import {UserService} from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  answers: MyClass[];
  users: User[];
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.answers = data;
      });
  }
}
```

I have a new class

```
import {User} from './user';
export class MyClass {
  message: string;
  error: string;
  users: User; /*{user: string, role: string; project: string};*/
}
```

and my template now looks like this

```
<h2>List of users</h2>
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>Name</div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>Role</div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>Project</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' *ngFor="let user of answers?.users">
        <div class='col-sm-4'>{{user.user}}</div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>{{user.role}}</div>
        <div class='col-sm-4'>{{user.project}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>{{answers?.message}} and {{answers?.error}}.</div>
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome on Windows 10 but doesn't work on Microsoft Edge.  Any ideas why this should be?

Comment: Regarding browser support, take a look at https://angular.io/guide/browser-support, and pay specific attention to what polyfills are about.